# How to generate a keystore to update a published app?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I am quite new to android, this question maybe quite simple. But i do need your help. I am preparing to submit a update to google play now. When i export the android application, there is a keystore selection dialog. But i don't have the keystore. The project was developed by another company before. Now we only have the source code and the google play developer account. After reading the [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp), i know i need to generate one. But there is still something i am not sure about this.

The keystore generate command as below:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This is a self-signed certificate. Is this sufficient for me to submit the update? Or need me to generate another one ? if so, then how to do that?

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating your own `Keystore` go to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin` and execute below command

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore app.keystore -alias app -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 300000
```

It'll created your `app.keystore` in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin` directory and by using this `keystore` you can sign you application. You must keep this `keystore` safe because of your app next update.

**Update:** command for generate SHA-1 from your `app.keystore`

```
D:>keytool -v -list -alias app -keystore "D:app.keystore" -storepass app -keypass app
```

Comment: Now i am updating an App. Can i use a new keystore?

Comment: No used your app older Keystore that you generated at First published

Comment: how if there is no previous keystore?

Comment: then there is no way you publish your app next update.

Comment: Why the .keystore mechanism is designed like this? it's very easy to lost the .keystore file.

Comment: @Chancy this is the only way you can secure your `apk` built otherwise i can also update your app if i have your app source code.

Comment: but how if i lost the .keystore? I think the key should be regenerated from the google developer account.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52377/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-chancy)

Answer (score 0):

Right click to the project --> select Android tools -->Export signed Application package

this bring you to window "Export  Android Application"

Complete the rest. this will give you signed apk as well as keystore

You can take help from this link too :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYhJp-jqJyM

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the original `keystore`, otherwise you won't be able to update the application on the Play Store. Ask the previous developer to give the one he used to sign the application, then save it in the safest place you can think of.